# Writing a file to disk then uploading to S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I got some code working to download an MP3 file using request and then upload to S3 trouble is when it got up there the file was corrupt. So trying to download to disk first but a lot of fs commands don't have a great callback. Any help you could provide would be helpful - still learning and getting the hang of async concepts

```
parser.parseURL('https://bridgetown.podbean.com/feed.xml', function (err, feed) {
  request(feed.items[0].enclosure.url).pipe(audioFile).on('close', function () {
    console.log("downloadfinsihed")
    s3.upload({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: "testperm3.mp3", Body: "Audio.mp3" }, function (err, data) {
      transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob({LanguageCode: "en-US", Media:{MediaFileUri: data.Location}, MediaFormat: "mp3", TranscriptionJobName: "testing"}, function (err, data){
                         //console.log(data);           
                });

          });
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a situation where using the promise-based async/await syntactic sugar might help to convert the callbacks to asynch versions.

Try something like this:

```
 parser.parseURL('https://bridgetown.podbean.com/ 
 feed.xml', async function (err, feed) {
    const res = await request(feed.items[0].enclosure.url).pipe(audioFile)
```

....

Comment: Thanks I think that worked but still the program is closing way too soon - here is the full code - tried using another promise down below

```parser.parseURL('https://bridgetown.podbean.com/feed.xml', async function (err, feed) {
    const res = await request(feed.items[0].enclosure.url).pipe(audioFile)
      if (res.err) {console.log("error")}
      else {
        s3.upload({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: "testperm5.mp3", Body: "audioFile.mp3" }, async function (err, data) {
          const up = await transcribeservice.startTranscriptionJob({-paramaters-}
```